# Does the Azure Data Lake Store offer any encryption?

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake

I am under the impression that the Azure Data Lake Store does not currently offer any encryption at rest (the way Azure Blob Storage does). I managed to found some vague mention of this on the official website, suggesting this is coming soon.

Is this your understanding as well? Does this cover the databases stored under the Azure Data Lake Analytics as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually encryption is available in preview on ADL Storage right now. If you contact us we can give you access to the preview.

Comment: Hi Michael, thank you for your reply! Just to be clear, it's not included in the Data Lake Store / Analytics functionality available on the Azure Portal, which is also in preview, but can be enabled on request and will be made GA at some point in the future?

Answer (score 0):

Azure Data Lake Store Encryption is currently Generally Available, not in preview any more. You can specify encryption at rest when creating ADLS in portal. Options are these:
[image]